# web audio api: multiply waves

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

The Web Audio API lets me create a constant sine wave in a specified frequence signal like this:

```
var actx = new AudioContext();
var osc = actx.createOscillator();

osc.frequency.value = 500;
osc.connect(actx.destination);
osc.start();
```

How can I multiply this wave by another wave in order to "shape" it. For example how could I multiply it by another sine wave of 200 Hz.

Like so:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like

```
var osc1 = context.createOscillator();
var osc2 = context.createOscillator();
var gain = context.createGain();

osc1.frequency.value = 500;
osc2.frequency.value = 20;

osc1.connect(gain);
osc2.connect(gain.gain);

gain.connect(context.destination);

osc1.start();
osc2.start();
```

Comment: your code works, great. So the gain is to be regarded as a multiplier. I didn't know that you can connect a signal also to the gain.gain property.

Comment: Of course, gain is a multiplier. :-) Then fun part is when the gain isn't a constant and can be from some other signal source.  This isn't really well-explained in the spec, but see http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#widl-AudioNode-connect-void-AudioParam-destination-unsigned-long-output

Comment: `AudioNode.connect()` comes in two flavours: `AudioNode.connect(AudioNode)` and `AudioNode.connect(AudioParam)`. The first one which can be used to connect the output of an AudioNode to the input of another one, and the second one which can be used to connect the output of an AudioNode to a AudioParam. And that's why you can do `osc2.connect(gain.gain)` in the code snippet provided by Raymond.

Comment: Is it actually possible to multiply more than two waves?  I want to fade in an amplitude modulation.  In the example answer above, I'd like osc2 amplitude (the modulation depth) to go from 0 to 1 over 10 seconds.  How can this be done? Tomasito665??  This relates to the original question, how to multiple waves (as opposed to just applying a waveform gain to one). Seems better for the moment to add this clarification here than start another whole question. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to multiply more than two waves.  If you want to do a*b, you need one gain node.  If you want to do a*b*c, you need 2 gain nodes.  One to multiply a*b (as shown above), then one to do (a*b)*c.